# Restricting app to for small screen, 2.7 inch (240 x 320)px resolution

Tags: android, screen

I am a newbie in android development. I want to restrict my app download  on small screen devices such as a 2.7 inch (240 x 320) px resolution screen.What will be the procedure to do it.
Please help ,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by declaring in your manifest the screen size you want to support using the tags `<supports-screen>` or `<compatible-screens>`

Docs:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element